# Can't add App Page as a Tab anymore?

Tags: facebook-page

have you had or known of anyone experiencing issues recently (this week) with creating a new Facebook app (developers.facebook.com/apps)? The issue being once the app is created, you now have to create the community page manually. Then when you go to the community page associated with your new app, it does not give you the ability (anymore) to add the app to your page anymore??? Any help or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a serious developer using the Facebook platform you should read the Facebook Developer blog: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/ and this tutorial from the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook changes their policy quite often.  As developers we are responsible for keeping our applications up to date.  Here is a link to the [Facebook Developers Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/), you should subscribe to updates from this blog and stay updated with regard to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/).

Your problem is detailed in [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) and the solutions is very simple - just substitute your values for this URL and open it
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL`